# bootstrap spacing in between two sections

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image: The white spacing]

```
<section id="mainmatter">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class ="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
<h1> The JuiceBox </h1>
</div><!--end col-->
</div><!--end row-->
</div><!--end container-->
</section> 

<section id="showcase">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class ="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
<div class="showcase-left">
<img src="images/juice.png" height=700 width=700>
</div>
</div>
<div class ="col-md-6col-sm-6">
<div class="showcase-right">
<p>    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, m.
</p>
</div>
</div><!--end col-->
</div><!--end container-->
</section>
```

/* SCSS code*/

```
#mainmatter{
margin-top: 250px;
margin-bottom: 270px;

h1{
font-family:$design-font;
font-size: 80px;
float:right;
}
}


#showcase
{
background-color: greenyellow;
padding-top:50px;
}

.showcase-left
{
margin-top:-70px;
}
.showcase-right{
margin-top:300px;
}
img{
margin-left:60px;
width:90%;
}

}
```

The above code looks fine with the desktop width. But, white space is appearing between two section on smaller screen.  What's wrong with my code?
Also the juice.png isn't getting bootstrapped.

Answer (score 0):

try to remove this style or reduce to 50px or less

```
.showcase-right{
margin-top:20px;
}
```